# yii 2 not working. Object not found. What?

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Installed yii2 advancedand set up .htaccess

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`
`Options +FollowSymlinks`
`RewriteEngine On`
`</IfModule>`

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(admin)`
`RewriteRule ^admin/assets/(.*)$ backend/web/assets/$1 [L]`
`RewriteRule ^admin/css/(.*)$ backend/web/css/$1 [L]`
`RewriteRule ^admin/js/(.*)$ backend/web/js/$1 [L]`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/backend/web/(assets|js|css|js)/`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(admin)`
`RewriteRule ^.*$ backend/web/index.php [L]`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(assets|css|js|images)`
`RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ frontend/web/assets/$1 [L]`
`RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ frontend/web/css/$1 [L]`
`RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ frontend/web/js/$1 [L]`
`RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ frontend/web/images/$1 [L]`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/$1 [L]`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(frontend|backend)/web/(assets|css|js)/`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
 `RewriteRule ^.*$ frontend/web/index.php`
`</IfModule>`

follow the link - /frontend/web/

and I get an error - 
[image: error image]

In what there can be an error. I have made all as in instructions?

Comment: just write /frontend without web

Comment: did not help, just write /frontend without web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously it get 404 Error. Because the `frontend/web` Rule is Rewrite using the **.htaccess** file.

Access your application **frontend** in `localhost` like

`http://localhost/your_project_directory_name/`

Comment: If I follow the link http://localhost/, there is my project, then an empty white page is displayed without an error.

Comment: Give full permission of your project directory ?

Comment: set permission, did not help

Comment: @RedSpace which os is used ?

Comment: Installed on windows 7.
Open Server Panel - Local web server for windows.

Comment: @RedSpace [Enabling mod_rewrite](https://webdevdoor.com/php/mod_rewrite-windows-apache-url-rewriting) in Apache for URL rewriting.

Comment: Everything did as it was written, did not help.